# How to Add missing Months and display TotalPayment = 0

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to Add missing Months and display TotalPayment as 0 
I already try row_number but it seems not working

Query:

```
  select brgy,
        datename(month,month_dt) as month_dt,
        TotalPayment
    from brgypayment
    order by brgy, month(month_dt)
```

Results:

> brgy  month_dt    TotalPayment
>  barangay1 January 5345.00
> barangay1 February    34232.00
>  barangay1 March   53454.00
> barangay1 April   25234.00
>  barangay1 May 43224.00
> barangay1 June    14.00
>  barangay1    July    141.00
> barangay1 August  4415.00
>  barangay1  September   5455.00
> barangay1 October 1235.00
>  barangay1  November    53535.00
> barangay1 December    1661.00
>  barangay2  January 97859.00
> barangay2 February    5673.00
>  barangay2  March   78764.00
> barangay2 April   84673.00
>  barangay2 May 63468.00
> barangay2 June    6365.00
>  barangay2  July    2145.00
> barangay2 August  4415.00
>  barangay2  September   62652.00
> barangay2 October 24521.00
>  barangay3 January 52345.00
> barangay3 February    15454.00

Target Results:

> brgy  month_dt    TotalPayment
>  barangay1 January 5345.00
> barangay1 February    34232.00
>  barangay1 March   53454.00
> barangay1 April   25234.00
>  barangay1 May 43224.00
> barangay1 June    14.00
>  barangay1    July    141.00
> barangay1 August  4415.00
>  barangay1  September   5455.00
> barangay1 October 1235.00
>  barangay1  November    53535.00
> barangay1 December    1661.00
>  barangay2  January 97859.00
> barangay2 February    5673.00
>  barangay2  March   78764.00
> barangay2 April   84673.00
>  barangay2 May 63468.00
> barangay2 June    6365.00
>  barangay2  July    2145.00
> barangay2 August  4415.00
>  barangay2  September   62652.00
> barangay2 October 24521.00
>  barangay2 November 0.00
> barangay2 December 0.00
>  barangay3    January 52345.00
> barangay3 February 15454.00
>  barangay3    March 0.00
> barangay3 April 0.00
>  barangay3   May  0.00
>  barangay3    June
> 0.00
>  barangay3   July 0.00
>  barangay3    August 0.00
>  barangay3  September 0.00
>  barangay3   October 0.00
> barangay3 November 0.00
>  barangay3    December 0.00

Comment: Do you have records for those missing months?

Comment: I don't have... I just need to display even no records

Comment: That complicates thing a lot. You will not be able to fetch the data by just an SQL query. You will have to use for loops and if statements to achieve what you want. Look for how to do while loops and if statements in SQL. Or simply insert the records for the missing months.

Comment: Okay. I think I'll go for making Stored Procedure and use loops and temp table. Inserting data is not possible because it is the actual record of payments that needs an audit. Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few ways to generate a list of months through direct SQL, with recursion, etc.  Very simple to do.  The above data doesn't seem to have a year component.  How do you plan to handle data for months that span from November, December to January and beyond?  Does `barangay1` refer to a year?

Comment: actually this is yearly report that needs to display all months per barangay for a specific year. Its all 2018. I just summarized it and make it simple to new sampleTable. FYI I am making cross-tab report.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Try searching for `[tsql] missing rows`. There are many similar questions out there.

Comment: @PeterD Not sure why you think loops are necessary, there are many ways to do this in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of distinct brgy names for the report, you can generate your months dynamically and then `CROSS JOIN` them with the list of brgy's of interest.  Now you can LEFT JOIN that list with your data to produce all brgy/month pairs, regardless of whether your data has every month for each brgy.

This is just one dynamic approach.  You could even create a static list of months to use.

Here's a working test case:

[Working Test Case for SQL Server / tsql (**Updated**)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b0887e78a8da9626575465c80b45cb2)

```
WITH months (month, monthname) AS (
         SELECT 1      , DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month,     0, 0)) UNION ALL
         SELECT month+1, DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, month, 0))
           FROM months
          WHERE month < 12
     )
   , list AS (
         SELECT b.*, m.*
           FROM months AS m
              , (SELECT DISTINCT bname FROM brgydata) AS b
     )
SELECT l.bname, l.monthname, COALESCE(b.amount, 0.0) AS amount
  FROM      list     AS l
  LEFT JOIN brgydata AS b
    ON b.bname     = l.bname
   AND b.monthname = l.monthname
 ORDER BY l.bname, l.month
;
```

See the following test case for a little sample:

The data:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| bname     | monthname | amount  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| barangay1 | January   | 5345.00 |
| barangay1 | February  |  123.00 |
| barangay1 | May       | 8000.00 |
| barangay2 | January   |   34.00 |
| barangay2 | February  |  111.00 |
| barangay2 | June      | 2000.00 |
| barangay2 | October   |  134.00 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

The result:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| bname     | monthname | amount  |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| barangay1 | January   | 5345.00 |
| barangay1 | February  |  123.00 |
| barangay1 | March     |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | April     |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | May       | 8000.00 |
| barangay1 | June      |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | July      |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | August    |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | September |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | October   |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | November  |    0.00 |
| barangay1 | December  |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | January   |   34.00 |
| barangay2 | February  |  111.00 |
| barangay2 | March     |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | April     |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | May       |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | June      | 2000.00 |
| barangay2 | July      |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | August    |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | September |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | October   |  134.00 |
| barangay2 | November  |    0.00 |
| barangay2 | December  |    0.00 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: The test data had a slight issue.  Corrected.

Comment: This is what exactly I want to do. Im not good working with recursion but I'll learn this. very thanks man

Answer (score 2):

To generate every combination of 'brgy' and month this CROSS JOIN's a virtual table called 'months_cte' containing the sequence 1, 2, ..., 12 with DISTINCT values of 'brgy'.  Something like this

```
drop TABLE if exists #brgypayment;
go
CREATE TABLE #brgypayment (
  brgy VARCHAR(40),
  month_dt date,
  TotalPayment decimal(10,2));

INSERT INTO #brgypayment VALUES
    ('barangay1', '2021-01-01', 5345.00)
  , ('barangay1', '2021-02-01', 123.00)
  , ('barangay1', '2021-05-01',     8000.00)
  , ('barangay1', '2021-07-01',   34.00)
  , ('barangay2', '2021-09-01', 111.00)
  , ('barangay2', '2021-11-01',    2000.00)
  , ('barangay2', '2021-12-01',  134.00);

with
unq_brgy_cte(brgy) as (
    select distinct brgy
    from #brgypayment),
months_cte(n) as (
    select * 
    from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(n))
select ub.brgy, datename(month, dateadd(month, m.n-1, 0)) month_dt,
       isnull(bp.TotalPayment, 0) TotalPayment
from unq_brgy_cte ub
     cross join months_cte m
     left join #brgypayment bp on ub.brgy=bp.brgy
                                  and m.n=month(bp.month_dt)
order by ub.brgy, m.n;
```